# where can i find python tutorials for doing linux tasks

Tags: python, linux, system-administration

I want to learn python to do some linux system administartion but on internet i find basic python tutorials . they don't teach anything with linux in mind but general python.

is there any pdf which can teach me how do linux things like backup , restore , mysql backups , log files processing in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [Popular recipes tagged "sysadmin"](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/tags/sysadmin/) on ActiveState. They are not tutorials in PDF but once you know Python you can learn a lot reading the source of recipes.

Answer (score 3):

I like the O'Reilly book [Python for Unix and Linux System Administration](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596515829?portal=oreilly&cid=orm-cat-readnow-9780596515829)